# Creating a binary variable based on a condition in a column

Tags: r

I am trying to create  binary variable inside the readmitted column in R :

[image]

if the value is is <30 then the the variable should = YES and anything else should = NO. This is the code I have but I am not sure how to get the else values.

```
HospitalData$readmitted <-  case_when(HospitalData$readmitted <30 ~ "YES" )
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. No not post images of data. It looks like your readmitted column is a character value, not numeric, so maybe try `case_when(HospitalData$readmitted == "<30" ~ "YES" )`

Comment: Sorry, the column was already present with these values before my code. When I try my code, It only replaces the values that are <30 with YES and N/A's everything else. I want everything that is not <30 to equal to NO

Comment: Then add `case_when(HospitalData$readmitted == "<30" ~ "YES", TRUE~"NO")` for all the other values.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: Since you have only two cases, `if_else` may be more simple: `if_else(HospitalData$readmitted == "<30", "YES", "NO")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty fast in data.table:

```
library(data.table)
HospitalData <- setDT(HospitalData)
HospitalData[,readmitted:=ifelse(readmitted == "<30", "YES", "NO")]
```